# willDisplayHeaderView not being called in TableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios11

Why is willDisplayHeaderView not being called in TableViewController?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(nonnull UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  //
}
```

---

***Edit:***

And heightForHeaderInSection

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  //
}
```

---

Deprecation?

XCODE Version 9.0 beta 5 (9M202q)

Comment: Share your complete code for tableivew, if wont call if you have not set header using `viewForHeader` method.

Comment: Thanks @Krunal !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Krunal! Your comment fixed it for iOS 11 (earlier iOS versions didn't have any problems)

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return myView;
}
```

Comment: Only after 24 hours ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case there is someone still having this issue, please ensure you set your tableview delegate and you implemented the **UITableViewDelegate**.